# NotSupportedException raised during InvokeMember call

Tags: c#, .net-cf-3.5

I'm using a **.NET CF 3.5** to create a dll and invoke a public member of the DLL from the exe.
The Dll code is given below :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DllPoc
{
    public class DllCheck
    {
        public String ReturnString()
        {
            return "Hello DLL";
        }
    }
}
```

and the exe code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    String _AppPath;
    String _AppImage;
    String _AppName;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //ReadAppLoaderXML();
        //StartApp();

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("\\test\\DllPoc.dll");
        Type type = assembly.GetType("DllPoc.DllCheck");
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        String s = (String)type.InvokeMember("RetrurnString",
                           BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | 
                           BindingFlags.Public, null, obj, null);
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        // Exit
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

On execution of the line:

```
String s = (String)type.InvokeMember("RetrurnString",
                            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | 
                            BindingFlags.Public, null, obj, null);
```

NotSupportedException is thrown.

Is this the correct procedure?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [`Type.InvokeMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx), the Exceptions section:

> - NotSupportedException
>     The .NET Compact Framework does not currently support this method.

Seems pretty clear to me that it's not supported on .NET CF, which is what you're using.

I really *hope* that `RetrurnString` wouldn't work anyway, and that you'd want `ReturnString`.

You may have more luck fetching the method (`Type.GetMethod`) and then calling `Invoke` on the `MethodInfo`. I don't see the same restriction there...

Comment: It appears that the overload that doesn't take a `CultureInfo` [is supported in CF 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @JeffMercado: We're looking at the same overload, just different versions of the documentation.